# JQuery ajax page request

Tags: jquery

I have a php calendar script that moves through the months using get vatiables e.g.

```
if(isset($_GET['chm'])) :
$m = ($_GET['prm'])+($_GET['chm']);
else: 
$m = date("m");
$y = date("Y");  // Find today's year
endif;
$d= date("d");  // Find today's date
$y= date("Y");  // Find today's year
$no_of_days = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$m,1,$y)); // This is to calculate number of days in a month
$mn=date('F',mktime(0,0,0,$m,1,$y)); // Month is calculated to display at the top of the calendar
$yn=date('Y',mktime(0,0,0,$m,1,$y)); // Year is calculated to display at the top of the calendar
$j= date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$m,1,$y)); // This will calculate the week day of the first day of the month
```

The calendar is displayed on the index page, what is the best way to use a JQuery Ajax request to update the calendat without a page refersh?

Is it to put the actual calendar on a separate page and call something like this?

```
var prm = $("#prm");
var chm = $("#chm");
$.ajax({type: "GET", url: "calendar.php", data: "&prm=" + prm + "&chm=" + chm,
            complete: function(data){
                calendardiv.html(data.responseText);

            }
         });
```

Help / comments appreciated thanks in adavance

Comment: Hey man, welcome to Stack Overflow! Was just looking over your question list, and wanted to make sure you know how important it is to mark answers as accepted. On your other questions, you can do that by clicking the grey check next to the right answer. Its the Stack Overflow way of rewarding the guys who answered your question correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Use the helper methods where you can to help simplify things. In this case, [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
// I assume you have this up farther in your code
// since it wasn't in the code you posted:
var calendardiv = $("#calendar");

var prm = $("#prm");
var chm = $("#chm");

calendardiv.load('calendar.php', { prm: prm.val(), chm: chm.val() });
```

This example assumes `prm` and `chm` were `input` elements. If they are normal HTML elements, than use `prm.text()` and `chm.text()` instead of `prm.val()` and `chm.val()`.

`load` sends a `GET` request to a page, passing the key/value pair as a normal query string  (i.e. you don't have to build it like `'&key=' + value`) and then replaces the `html` content of the element with the return value.